# How can I convert a wavy line animation in JS to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, requestanimationframe, svg-animate

I have implemented this wavy line animation and it works fine, but the problem is that I must convert it to React. I'm pretty new to React, should I use "useState" and "useEffect"?

Here's the code:

```
let xs = []
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  xs.push(i)
}

let t = 0

function animate() {

  let points = xs.map(x => {
   let y = 200 + 8 * Math.sin((x + t) /5)
    
    return [x, y]
  })

  let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
    return p[0] + "," + p[1]
  }).join(" L")

  document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("d", path)

  t += 0.5

  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()


<div className="Startpage">
 <svg>
  <path d="M10,10 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `xs`?

Comment: React is just a framework for pages/components.  You don't need to "convert" it to React.  The only important thing seems to be when do you want to initiate the animate() call.

Comment: @StudioTime Sorry! The first sentence was hidden.

Comment: @Seano666 Thanks! Yes, that was the problem. It calling the function now after the DOM content has been loaded. And it seems to work.